# RegEx and QueryString

Tags: c#, regex, query-string

i have this regex that i use with my website

```
^.*/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+)/$
```

My question is who i can use querystring with my regex,

/about-us/contact/?l=en -> page.aspx?id=12&l=en

where id=1 = /about-us/contact/

where l=en = /?l=en

EDIT:

```
^.*/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+)/(\?l=en)
```

i get error on this : \ i C#

Is there a way in regex to tell if ?x=x exist the regex is a match, but if ?x=x don't exist the regex for /about-us/contact/ is a match?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a `?` character in your search pattern, you just have to escape it with a backslash.  So if you want to find 'l=en', you look for '\?l=en'

```
^.*/([a-z0-9,-]+)/([a-z0-9,-]+)/(\?l=en)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression

```
[\?&](?<name>[^&=]+)=(?<value>[^&=]+)
```

Description 
Matches name/value pairs in HTTP Query Strings, placing name into group named "name" and value into group named "value"

Matches-->http://stackoverflow.com/?a=b&c=d

Non-Matches-->http://stackoverflow.com/

Author Rating: Kevin Spencer.